# How to get the "typeof" of a custom user control

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-3.5

I have a custom user control DatePicker.cs. Inside of another piece of code I have a collection of controls where I am checking the type of the control and doing some logic based on the type. My problem is the following:

```
typeof(DatePicker)
```

Evalutes to:

```
{Name = "DatePicker" FullName = "cusitecore.cedarsc.UserControls.DatePicker"}
```

But when I run the debugger and look at the type of the control that is on my web form it is:

```
{Name = "cedarsc_usercontrols_datepicker_ascx" FullName = "ASP.cedarsc_usercontrols_datepicker_ascx"}
```

These two things aren't equal so the correct logic isn't getting evaluated. I've tried using Type.GetType("ASP.cedarsc_usercontrols_datepicker_ascx") but this returns null.

**EDIT**

Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
private readonly Dictionary<Type, ControlType?> _controlTypes = new Dictionary<Type, ControlType?>
    {
        {typeof(CheckBox), ControlType.CheckBox},
        {typeof(CheckBoxList), ControlType.CheckBoxList},
        {typeof(DropDownList), ControlType.DropDownList},
        {typeof(HiddenField), ControlType.HiddenField},
        {typeof(ListBox), ControlType.ListBox},
        {typeof(RadioButton), ControlType.RadioButton},
        {typeof(RadioButtonList), ControlType.RadioButtonList},
        {typeof(TextBox), ControlType.TextBox},
        {typeof(Label), ControlType.Label},
        {typeof(DatePicker), ControlType.DatePicker},
        {typeof(CustomSelect), ControlType.CustomSelect}
    };

private void PopulateFields(Control control)
{
    ControlType? controlType;
    _controlTypes.TryGetValue(control.GetType(), out controlType);

    // recurse over the children
    if (control.Controls.Count > 0 && controlType == null) // don't want to recurse into children of controls we are reading values of
    {
        foreach(Control childControl in control.Controls)
        {
            PopulateFields(childControl);
        }
    }

    if (controlType != null)
    {
        switch (controlType)
        {
            case ControlType.CheckBox:
            case ControlType.RadioButton:
                CheckBox checkBox = control as CheckBox;
                    if (checkBox != null)
                        _fields.AddFieldValue(checkBox.ID, checkBox.Checked ? "Checked" : "Not Checked");
                    break;
            case ControlType.CheckBoxList:
            case ControlType.ListBox:
            case ControlType.RadioButtonList:
                ListControl listControl = control as ListControl;
                if (listControl != null)
                    _fields.AddFieldValue(listControl.ID, String.Join(", ", listControl.Items.Cast<ListItem>().Where(item => item.Selected).Select(item => item.Value).ToArray()));
                break;
            case ControlType.DropDownList:
                DropDownList dropDownList = control as DropDownList;
                if (dropDownList != null)
                    _fields.AddFieldValue(dropDownList.ID, dropDownList.SelectedValue);
                break;
            case ControlType.HiddenField:
                HiddenField hiddenField = control as HiddenField;
                if (hiddenField != null)
                    _fields.AddFieldValue(hiddenField.ID, hiddenField.Value);
                break;
            case ControlType.TextBox:
                TextBox textBox = control as TextBox;
                if (textBox != null)
                    _fields.AddFieldValue(textBox.ID, textBox.Text);
                break;
            case ControlType.DatePicker:
                DatePicker datePicker = control as DatePicker;
                if (datePicker != null)
                    _fields.AddFieldValue(datePicker.ID, datePicker.Text);
                break;
            case ControlType.CustomSelect:
                CustomSelect customSelect = control as CustomSelect;
                if(customSelect != null)
                    _fields.AddFieldValue(customSelect.ID, customSelect.SelectedValue);
                break;
            case ControlType.Label:
                Label label = control as Label;
                if(label != null)
                    _fields.AddFieldLabel(label.AssociatedControlID, label.Text);
                break;
            default:
                throw new Exception("Unhandled Control");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide some more context?  What do your code look like that is trying to perform the comparison between the two types?

Comment: ASP.NET creates it's own type inherited from the user control. Use the `is` keyword for comparisons and try `control.GetType().BaseType` for extraction.

Comment: @Jaroslav this is the answer. Slap that down at the bottom so we can give you credit :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

ASP.NET creates it's own type inherited from user controls.

For comparisons use the `is` operator.
For extractions use `control.GetType().BaseType`.

Comment: The only problem with this seems to be that calling .BaseType on a native control returns "WebControl". So for instance for a control which is a TextBox, control.GetType().BaseType is "WebControl". Any thoughts?

Comment: Based on naming conventions, classname should not contain `_`. So if the type `EndsWith("_ascx")`, you can be pretty sure it is a user control and extract the name as explained in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Your post doesn't quite go into how you are intending to use this, but I never had any problems with typeof() being used in my events.  For example, I would have the following if-statement in an event dealing with hovering:

```
if (sender.GetType() == typeof(Transparent_Panel))
```

where Transparent_Panel was a custom user control.  I never did any special under-the-hood work with Tansparent_Panel to make this work.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using the keyword `is`. It's not quite the same thing but if all you are trying to do is determine if an object is of a certain type (or extends/implements a class/interface) then that should do the trick.

Of course depending on your code this may not help.

Comment: I just had this problem today and (myControl is TypeICareAbout) worked. The "is" keyword checks to see if the variable can be cast to the desired type without throwing an error. See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scekt9xw(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 1):

ASP.NET 2.0 and later will compile the `UserControl` to the Temporary ASP.NET Files directory on-demand, so the type you are inspecting when you look at the type of the control in the debugger is being automatically generated by the ASP.NET compilation engine. The good news is that this type inherits from the `DatePicker` type, so the following code should work to test whether a given `UserControl` is actually a `DatePicker`:

```
typeof(DatePicker).IsAssignableFrom(userControl.GetType().BaseType)
```

Alternatively, you could always create an instance of the `DatePicker` `UserControl` at runtime and check for type equivalence via:

```
LoadControl(typeof(DatePicker)).GetType() == userControl.GetType()
```

Sources: [Compilation and Deployment in ASP.NET 2.0](http://www.west-wind.com/presentations/AspNetCompilation/AspNetCompilation.asp#_Page_Compilation_in)