# Match type of control with base class

Tags: c#, asp.net, types, matching

So I got the following class...

```
public partial class CommandBar : UserControl { .. }
```

...which i include in the .ascx file like so...

```
<%@ Register Src="~/.../CommandBar.ascx" TagName="CommandBar" TagPrefix="uc1" %>

...

<uc1:CommandBar ID="CommandBarTop" runat="server" ... />
```

My goal at the moment is to create a generic method which allows a user to set all controls to readonly recursively. The method should provide an optional parameter to specify a `List<Type>` of controls to ignore. In this list I want to pass this CommandBar with `typeof(CommandBar)` to ignore those.

Everything works like expected but I'm having a little trouble figguring out the proper way to match these types.

Consider the following;

```
Object o; // control to check, in this case the `CommandBarTop` object
Type t; // type to ignore
```

I expected it to be as easy like this:

```
if (o is t){
    // ignore
}
```

... but I get a syntax exception "A constant value is expected". So i tried it with the following setup:

```
if (t == typeof(o)){
    // ignore
}
```

It did compile but did not work like expected. The problem seems to be a type missmatch. Taking a look at the debugger I get the following:

```
t => {Name = "CommandBar" FullName = "My.Name.Space.Controls.CommandBar"}   System.Type {System.RuntimeType}
o => {ASP.controls_commandbar_ascx} object {ASP.controls_commandbar_ascx}
```

`o.base` is actually of type `t` but first of all it is not accessible and second the method should be generic, checking a base type to match would probably not always do what I want.

I assume that ASP.NET generates a control wrapper at runtime which then gets sent to the user. This assumption is based on the assembly codebase I see in the debugger. It says the following:

```
t.Assembly.CodeBase => "file:///.../bin/My.Name.Space.Project.DLL"  string
o.GetType().Assembly.CodeBase => "file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/.../Temporary ASP.NET Files/root/.../App_Web_....DLL"  string
```

I also tried matching the type GUID but since they are basically not the same type that doesn't work either.

---

**EDIT 1**

I thought it might help if I show you my method to set the controls to readonly recursively

```
public static void SetControlRecursivelyReadOnly(Object control, Boolean readOnly, IEnumerable<Type> controlTypesToIgnore = null)
{
    if (null == control)
    {
        return;
    }

    new List<KeyValuePair<Type, String>>
    {
        // define all types which are relevant to access possible child controls
        new KeyValuePair<Type, String>(typeof(ControlCollection), "Controls"),
        new KeyValuePair<Type, String>(typeof(TableRow), "Rows"),
        new KeyValuePair<Type, String>(typeof(TableCell), "Cells")
    }.ForEach(x =>
              {
                  // get defined property
                  Object property = typeof(Reflection).GetMethod("GetProperty")
                                                      .MakeGenericMethod(x.Key)
                                                      .Invoke(null,
                                                              new[]
                                                              {
                                                                  control,
                                                                  x.Value
                                                              });

                  // check if property is found and is IENumerable
                  if (!(property is IEnumerable))
                  {
                      return; // continues the foreach loop
                  }

                  // call recursive
                  foreach (Object o in (IEnumerable) property)
                  {
                      // <--- TODO CHECK IF CONTROL TYPE SHOULD BE IGNORED --->
                      SetControlRecursivelyReadOnly(o, readOnly);
                  }
              });

    // set relevant properties accordingly to readOnly parameter
    new List<Tuple<PropertyInfo, Boolean>>
            {
                new Tuple<PropertyInfo, Boolean>(control.GetType().GetProperty("ReadOnly"), readOnly),
                new Tuple<PropertyInfo, Boolean>(control.GetType().GetProperty("EnableButtons"), !readOnly),
                new Tuple<PropertyInfo, Boolean>(control.GetType().GetProperty("Enabled"), !readOnly)
            }.Where(x => null != x.Item1)
             .ToList()
             .ForEach(x => x.Item1.SetValue(control, x.Item2, null));
}
```

---

Coming to my question now; anyone got an idea how to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean when you talk about components? Maybe "Controls" (TextBox, Label...)? Can you add some examples?

Comment: @Emanuele yes sir, I mean controls. I've updated my question accordingly. the examples you gave with TextBox, Label aso. is exactly what I mean. Ofc there are also Panels, Tables, DropDownLists, .. which sometimes have a property called "Controls", "Rows" or "Cells" themselfs, thats why I implement it recursively to get to all controls within the page

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop recursively all Controls in your page.

```
    public void FindChildControlsRecursive(Control control)
    {
        foreach (Control childControl in control.Controls)
        {
            // add .BaseType in the next line if it's a UserControl
            if (childControl.GetType() == typeof(T))
            {
                _foundControls.Add((T)childControl);
            }
            else
            {
                FindChildControlsRecursive(childControl);
            }
        }
    }

    private readonly List<T> _foundControls = new List<T>();
    public IEnumerable<T> FoundControls
    {
       get { return _foundControls; }
    }
```

In the same way you can set a property containing controls to exclude.

You can check: [How to get the "typeof" of a custom user control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4949078/how-to-get-the-typeof-of-a-custom-user-control)

Comment: I already have the recursive function, that is not the problem. the problem is the matching of the type. your approach with `control.GetType() == typeof(T)` does not work. because T is already a Type, calling typeof(T) will return a RuntimeType which is not what I need. also because the control is not of the same type it will not work. read my question again

Comment: Sorry, i'd edit my post. Try to use BaseType. I'd check my solution on VS.

Comment: Yes, BaseType indeed refers to the correct type, matching with this should work. The problem is if I implement it to always check the BaseType I'm pretty sure that this will not work most at the time, because the BaseType of pretty much every Control is `WebControl`.. If I tell the method to ignore WebControl then nothing will happen. I already thought of this approach but it seems that I'd run into problems pretty fast

Comment: I checked my solution. Adding BaseType is correct for UserControl (ascx). The previous code works for Webcontrol. I edited my post adding another interesting post.

Comment: thanks for the effort, but I'm still not trying to *FIND* controls, I'm just trying to match their type and ignore them in my function. I'll update my question and add the method I use to set recursive readonly

Comment: Have you tried to put all controls in a Panel and set Enable=false on that?

Comment: yes I did, the problem is that not every control should be disabled, that's the whole point of the check I'm trying to implement

Answer (score 0):

Try with the name prop of your type. Something like below should work

`if (typeof(o).Name == t.GetType().Name)
 {
    // ignore
 }`

Comment: calling `.GetType()` on t (which already is of type `Type`) will return a `System.RuntimeType` .. this will not work. also the name is not the same